# Extend: 2D into 1D using extend function in python3

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, 2d

Merging 2D array in 1D array using extend function in python so what is the space complexity ?

Comment: NO merge is Convert

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.